# date beetween and query giving error

Tags: cakephp

```
$attData= $attendeesTable->find()->where( [
    'meeting_id =' => $meeting_id,
    'email =' => $data['email'],
    'created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?'=> array(
        $finaldate,
        $enddate
    )
])
->count();
```

Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object
File `/var/www/webinar.mj/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Type/DateTimeType.php`
Line: 104

Comment: What's the method call on Line 104?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right way to do this is

```
$attData= $attendeesTable->find()
->where([
    'meeting_id =' => $meeting_id,
    'email =' => $data['email']
])
->where(function ($exp, $q) use($finaldate, $enddate) {
    $exp->between('created_at ', $finaldate, $enddate);
    return $exp;
})
->count();
```

you can also do

```
$attData= $attendeesTable->find()->where( [
    'meeting_id =' => $meeting_id,
    'email =' => $data['email'],
    'created_at BETWEEN :foo AND :bar'
])
->bind(':foo', $finaldate, 'date') 
->bind(':bar', $enddate, 'date') ;
->count();
```

Comment: Thanks a lots @arilia